# how to use a variable in req.body - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

what I want to do is to get data from a form
but the form is being generated dynamically and so I wont know how many rows will come out.
so for the form I have (using ejs)

```
<form action="/attendance-data" method="post">
     <% var i=0 %>
<% rows.forEach(function(item){ %>
       <% i=i+1 %>
     <tr>
          <td><%= i+"." %></td>
        <td id="uan<%= i %>"> <%= item.uan  %> </td>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><%= item.designation %></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="attendance<%= i %>" ></td>
     </tr>
    <% });   %>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

here i changes from 1 to 10 or whatever the length of the data is.
so, example
the form name goes from attendance1, attendance2, attendance3,.....

in the server side i am using

```
app.post('/attendance-data',function(req,res){
    var  daysPresent;
    var attendance;
    for(var i=1;i<=numberOfEmployees;i++){

        attendance = "attendance"+i;
        daysPresent = req.body.attendance;
        console.log('attendance is :',attendance);
        console.log('days present is :',daysPresent);
    }

});
```

here I want to get the value of the days present from the form for each loop.
so, first loop , it gets req.body.attendance1
second it gets req.body.attendance2  ,
and so on
but when I use the variable attendance instead of attendance1 and attendance2 
directly, then i get undefined as a result.

I am only getting a result when I directly use req.body.attendance1 or req.body.attendance2 or something similar.

why is this happening?
why cant I use the attendance variable which gets all the values from attendance1 , attendance2, ......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line grabbing the value of daysPresent:

```
daysPresent = req.body.attendance;
```

Should be:

```
daysPresent = req.body[attendance]
```

Comment: OMG! it worked.

as simple as that??
did I mention how much I love you??

Comment: could you answer this for me.
I'd like to put this in the database as the next step. so should I just put the command 
connect.query( insert into .....

inside the loop itself??